# Can't establish a reliable connection to the server google play?

Tags: google-play-store, samsung-galaxy-s-3, root-access, google

Ok so i have samsung galaxy s3 i rooted it a week ago and it worked flawless then afterward when today i opened google play it says no connection .i tried all methods like setting date and time cleaned data and cache but nothing orked the last option i was left with was factory reset i did it but nothing worked when it restarted it asked for google account and when i tried to sign in it prompt saying cant establish a reliable connection .Now when i researched more about it i came to know about a file hosts and to edit it i installed total commander when i tried to edit it it closed saying not enough memory but when i opened it with es file explorer it opened when i put a # mark before everything and saved it it gives an error saying it cannot be save 
file size of hosts is 1.1mb 
please help any help will be appreciated

Answer (score -1):

Try to use root browser,enable root browsing, find the hosts file and add a # and a space after it. Save it and reboot your device. In some cases you need to clear data and cache.